# How do I check for a condition before writing an empty file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to read all rows in data.csv and if the value is Los Angeles for the City column, then it would add that row to match.csv but I don't want it to create match.csv with a header and empty rows if there are no rows with Los Angeles in the City column from data.csv.  How do I do this?

```
with open("data.csv", 'r') as input_file, open("match.csv", 'w') as output_file:
    data_reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
    match_write = csv.DictWriter(output_file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=data_reader.fieldnames)
    match_write.writeheader()
    for row in data_reader:
        if row['City'] == "Los Angeles":
            match_write.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Count the matching rows before creating the writer? You will either have to read the file twice or keep the matching rows in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just don't want to create the header, and are fine with an empty file, then don't create the writer until the first instance of Los Angeles.  For example, this wouldn't add the header to the file `match.csv` unless there is a row with Los Angeles:

```
match_write = None

with open("data.csv", 'r') as input_file, open("match.csv", 'w') as output_file:
    data_reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
    for row in data_reader:
        if row['City'] == "Los Angeles":
            if match_write is None:
                match_write = csv.DictWriter(output_file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=data_reader.fieldnames)
                match_write.writeheader()
            match_write.writerow(row)
```

However, if the `match.csv` file shouldn't be created at all unless there is an instance of Los Angeles, then the file shouldn't be opened either until the first instance.

```
output_file = None

with open("data.csv", 'r') as input_file:
    data_reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
    for row in data_reader:
        if row['City'] == "Los Angeles":
            if output_file is None:
                output_file = open("match.csv", 'w')
                match_write = csv.DictWriter(output_file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=data_reader.fieldnames)
                match_write.writeheader()
            match_write.writerow(row)

if output_file is not None:
    output_file.close()
```